# Probability of external physical factors corrupting computer data and calculations?

Tags: security, hardware-failure

In the discussion of unreasonably bad sorts, there was [an answer that claims alpha particles flipping memory bits can be used as a sorting algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6947808/3664611).

Which makes me wonder: How probable do external radiation, voltage fluctuations, or such physical factor corrupt data or calculations (i.e modifies them), and how much impact can they make? And what countermeasures have been made to tackle with these unexpected corruptions?

For example, if say, an alpha particle hits the CPU and flipped a register from 0 to 1, it then becomes totally possible that some comparisons or pointer jumps later may fail, and crash the program because of unexpected behavior resulted the corrupt of data. Or in a mild case, returns 3 when it's calculating 1+1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how probable soft errors in CPUs are (I think they are quite rare because the CPU-package should shield from alpha radiation), but they can appear with DRAM memory. That is why you can buy automatically error-correcting RAM (called ECC-DRAM) for servers and other high-reliability applications.

You can find many studies on DRAM-fault-rates, e.g. this one: http://softerrors.info/selse/images/selse_2012/Papers/selse2012_submission_4.pdf